# CSS Clip-path positioning issues

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes, clip-path

I have created a fairly simple shape using an SVG element which is then put into my CSS using `clip-path`. It should make the corners rounded for me but for some reason only 1 of the corners does the effect perfectly.

This is the shape:

```html
<svg height="500" width="500">

  <path fill="#555555" d="M50,0 L450,0 Q500,0 500,50 L500,400 Q500,450 450,450 L200,450 L175,500 L150,450 L50,450 Q0,450 0,400 L0,50 Q0,0 50,0z" />

</svg>
```

This is what happens when i use it as a `clip-path`

```css
body {
  background: #555;
}
img {
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M50,0 L450,0 Q500,0 500,50 L500,400 Q500,450 450,450 L200,450 L175,500 L150,450 L50,450 Q0,450 0,400 L0,50 Q0,0 50,0z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://dummyimage.com/500" />
```

It seems to work perfectly within FireFox but shows the corners aren't cut correctly in Chrome apart from the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [default units for the `clip-path` is `userSpaceOnUse`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#clipPath-geometry) and this seems to calculate the coordinates of the path with reference to the root element. This is the reason why the `clip-path` seems like it is producing an incorrect output. Nullifying the `margin` and `padding` on the root element or absolutely positioning the element (like in the below snippet) should solve the issue.

```css
body {
  background: #555;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M50,0 L450,0 Q500,0 500,50 L500,400 Q500,450 450,450 L200,450 L175,500 L150,450 L50,450 Q0,450 0,400 L0,50 Q0,0 50,0z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" />
```

---

However, in a real life scenario the actual element that has to be clipped could be present anywhere within the body and hence I think it is a much better approach to use the `objectBoundingBox` as the units like in the below snippet:

```css
body {
  background: #555;
}
img {
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M0.1,0 L0.9,0 Q1,0 1,0.1 L1,0.8 Q1,0.9 0.9,0.9 L0.4,0.9 L0.35,1 L0.3,0.9 L0.1,0.9 Q0,0.9 0,0.8 L0,0.1 Q0,0 0.1,0z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://dummyimage.com/500" />
```

---

As mentioned in the question itself, this behavior is visible only in Chrome and not Firefox for reasons unknown to me. Firefox produces an output similar to the expected one even when (a) extra padding + margin is added to the body and (b) when the image itself is wrapped inside another container which also has padding + margin.

The only case where Firefox's output matches with Chrome is when a `padding` is added directly to the `img` tag itself. I believe this happens because `padding` is part of the element and thus affects the coordinates.

Comment: Just FYI, it is not required to have the SVG in your template / code base. You can simply use CSS `clip-path` with the path like:


`clip-path: path('M0.1,0 L0.9,0 Q1,0 1,0.1 L1,0.8 Q1,0.9 0.9,0.9 L0.4,0.9 L0.35,1 L0.3,0.9 L0.1,0.9 Q0,0.9 0,0.8 L0,0.1 Q0,0 0.1,0z');`

Answer (score 0):

To use an SVG clip-path with CSS only, you can simply do:

```css
img {
    clip-path: path('M0.1,0 L0.9,0 Q1,0 1,0.1 L1,0.8 Q1,0.9 0.9,0.9 L0.4,0.9 L0.35,1 L0.3,0.9 L0.1,0.9 Q0,0.9 0,0.8 L0,0.1 Q0,0 0.1,0z');
}
```

This way you don't need an `<svg>` element in the Template or HTML.