# how to use a div with clip-path instead of svg

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

in the example below - `svg` is a wave I want to have on the bottom side of div
so trying to use a div with `clip-path` instead of svg
referencing the path by `clip-path:url`- doesn't work
I also tried to copy all path nodes - i.e. `clip-path:d="M0,64L60...` - without success
pls help

```css
.clip-01{
    height:140px;
    background:lightblue;
    clip-path:url(#path01);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 65"><path id='path01' fill="lightblue" d="M0,64L60,53.3C120,43,240,21,360,10.7C480,0,600,0,720,10.7C840,21,960,43,1080,48C1200,53,1320,43,1380,37.3L1440,32L1440,0L1380,0C1320,0,1200,0,1080,0C960,0,840,0,720,0C600,0,480,0,360,0C240,0,120,0,60,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>

<br><br>

<div class='clip-01'></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603812/css-clip-path-positioning-issues

Comment: @Paulie_D - thanks but can't find solution for my scenario on your link

Comment: You need to wrap you path in a `<clipPath>`  element that needs the ID referenced in your css (path01). Clip-paths have admittedly some pitfalls - but you really need to pay more attention to the syntax since there are a plethora of similar but different [approaches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). Not to mention yet varying browser support for some features ...

Comment: @herrstrietzel - did you try ? `<clipPath id='path01'></clipPath>` around `<path></path> - just moves down the path and doesnt show my rectangle div - 140px height